# How to create a custom DataLoader for Huggingface Trainer that can load multiple files?

Tags: machine-learning, pytorch, huggingface-transformers, pytorch-dataloader, huggingface-datasets

I'm following Huggingface's [tutorial](https://huggingface.co/learn/nlp-course/chapter7/6) on training a causal language model. They have a `DataLoader` that loads their **one** file at a time:

```
from torch.utils.data.dataloader import DataLoader

tokenized_dataset.set_format("torch")
train_dataloader = DataLoader(tokenized_dataset["train"], batch_size=32, shuffle=True)
eval_dataloader = DataLoader(tokenized_dataset["valid"], batch_size=32)
```

However, in my case I have multiple files that I cannot combine into one as they don't fit into memory. So I have multiple such `tokenized_dataset` in a folder:

```
tokenized_datasets = [tokenized_dataset_1, tokenized_dataset_2, ... tokenized_dataset_10000]
```

Similar to their script, each `tokenized_dataset` in my case has a column called `input_ids` which should be used as inputs and labels, as done in the causal language modeling training.

How can I modify the `DataLoader` such that it will use my `tokenized_datasets` files separately? I don't need them all to be shuffled simultaneously at each epoch, but optimally the order of files will be shuffled (i.e., not the same order of files to be trained on at each epoch), and also within each file the order of the input ids will be shuffled.

Comment: Will this answer your question? https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/dataloader-for-a-folder-with-multiple-files-pytorch-solutions-that-is-equivalent-to-tfrecorddataset-in-tf2-0/70512/4. You can basically shuffle the file names before the for loop.

Comment: @TYZ Potentially, I'm trying to modify it to be used with my settings. I'll let you know if this works! Thanks for the help!